# Parsing LUIS prediction result entities JSON

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Is there a library or set of helper functions to parse the JSON objects returned from LUIS predictions in C#?  I found a blog that does some custom parsing of date and money entities, but in the context of the Bot Framework.  It seems to be outdated

http://martink.me/articles/bot-framework-v4-with-luis

Comment: Just doing a cursory scan of the blog you posted, it didn't actually seem like out-dated knowledge to me. The set-up is pretty similar to the SDK's sample with dispatch. Or [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/BookingDialog.cs).

Comment: Here also in the Functional Tests section, it uses the same dialog to book a flight, but also includes a [BookingDetails class to hold the various entities that can be extracted](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/FunctionalTests/Skills/DialogToDialog/DialogSkillBot/Dialogs/BookingDialog.cs#L87)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for more than just the LuisRecognizer? The official [class documentation for .NET is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.luis.luisrecognizer?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). I use the nodejs version for entity and top intent extraction, though I haven't used it for complex entity extraction like datetime and money.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but I've already called LuisClient.Prediction.GetSlotPredictionAsync for the prediction and am looking to parse the results.  Is this for getting the prediction?  Also says the API is obsolete.  thanks